# I want to compress an audio file to a smaller size before uploading to server php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building a web app for users to upload audio files but want the audio files compressed to a smaller size before uploading to the server. I have been able to compress the image upload part but have no idea about audio upload. I tried ffmeg but didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you manage to compress the images before upload with PHP?

Comment: Yes I have been able to compress images successfully and uploaded to the server. I  now want to compress audio file to smaller size before uploading to the server too. Thanks

Comment: Impressive that you managed to compress an image before it's on the server with a server programming language. I'm quite sure you are the only one who has managed with that.

Comment: No I PHP getimagesize function to do that while uploading to server.

Comment: No, when fully uploaded to server. Everything you do in php is on the server. Nothing can be before upload or while uploaded with php.

Comment: Alright. So please how can I compress audio file size to a smaller size while uploading to server? Thanks

Comment: You need to use one of the tags I added

Comment: I have saved the edit so hoping to get an answer. Thanks

Comment: search on "javascript audio compression"

Comment: Are you recording audio on the page ? Which format is the audio ?

Comment: I am taking audio files from user to a server